# How to add paprika flavor to mayonnaise without paprika color

Tags: mayonnaise, paprika

My homemade mayonnaise is always a little "flat" tasting compared to commercial. Most commercial mayo includes paprika, which I do not. How does one add paprika flavor to homemade mayo without imparting an unappetizing red/orange color to the finished product?

The ingredients used in my mayonnaise are as follows:

- 2 large egg yolks
- 1.25 cup soybean oil
- 1.66 tbsp white vinegar
- 1.5 tsp yellow mustard
- 0.25 tsp powdered sugar
- 0.5 tsp table salt
- 1 tbsp lemon juice

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you know for sure that will be the result? I am guessing that the labels you are reading also include many other ingredients that heighten the flavor.  Can you provide a list of ingredients?  That way we can help you lift the taste of your mayo without altering the color.

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding paprika to my mayonnaise. It definitely changes the color.

Comment: Added my ingredient list

Comment: Not all commercial mayonnaise lists paprika as an ingredient, though they do tend to say natural flavors. Of the two I found that do, one said "oleoresin paprika" (paprika *extract*), not paprika. Note that it's still a color, not just a flavor, but in the quantities it's used in, it's likely more about deepening the yellow-orange you expect from egg yolks than turning things red. (It's also used to color cheese and orange juice.) So I'm not actually sure it's your missing flavor.

Comment: Oleoresins from chili plants have flavor for sure @Jefromi

Comment: @GdD I know, but if the quantity is only enough to provide a little hint of yellow, I'm not sure if the amount of flavor is enough that missing it would leave the mayo tasting flat, especially since not all recipes/brands seem to use it.

Comment: A sensible thing for the OP to do would be to add some paprika to the mayo and see if that's the missing flavor, then if that tastes good could try some oleoresin paprika @Jefromi

Comment: @Isaac16 What I meant was to list the ingredients of the commercial mayo that you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

My personal method for adding flavor to homemade mayonnaise is to include some flavored oil in addition to the vegetable oil. I like just a touch of chili oil (a teaspoon or so -- too much, and it gets too spicy and/or weirdly red).

Paprika-infused oil can be purchased or made at home ([Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=paprika%20oil)) -- this may meet your needs, or inspire you to try other flavors. (You can also try infused vinegars!)